# setInterval issue with get message function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a method to retrieve messages from a database. I use `setInterval()` on that method (for real time chat)

The problem is that when I click on another user I get the messages again from that user (without refreshing). After that the function starts to bring messages from 2 users at the same time, from the first user and from the second user. It's like I cloned the function to work twice on different users. How can I fix this problem?

```js
function open_message_box(thread_id, now, x = false) {
  $("#msg_body").html("<div class='text-center' id='payment_loader'><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-5x fa-spin'></i></div>");
  $("#msg_box_header").html("<a class='c-base-1' target='_blank' href='<?=base_url()?>home/member_profile/" + $(now).find('.contacts-list-name').data('member') + "'>" + $(now).find('.contacts-list-name').html() + "</a>");
  $("#msg_refresh").html("<a onclick='refresh_msg(" + thread_id + ")'><i class='fa fa-refresh'></i> <?=translate('refresh')?></a>");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>home/get_messages/" + thread_id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      clearInterval(message_interval);
      var message_interval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#msg_body").load('<?=base_url()?>home/get_messages/' + thread_id);
      }, 3000);
      $("#msg_body").removeAttr("style");
      $("#message_text").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#message_text").val('');
      $("#msg_body").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the scope of your variables.

When you define `var message_interval` inside your success function it will only be available inside that function.

This means that when you clear the interval with `clearInterval(message_interval)`, the `message_interval` is undefined. You might think that it's the previous `message_interval` but it's not.

One simple way to fix this would be to declare your variable outside of the function and define it when needed.

Something like this should work.

```
var message_interval;

function open_message_box(thread_id, now, x = false) {
  $("#msg_body").html("<div class='text-center' id='payment_loader'><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-5x fa-spin'></i></div>");
  $("#msg_box_header").html("<a class='c-base-1' target='_blank' href='<?=base_url()?>home/member_profile/" + $(now).find('.contacts-list-name').data('member') + "'>" + $(now).find('.contacts-list-name').html() + "</a>");
  $("#msg_refresh").html("<a onclick='refresh_msg(" + thread_id + ")'><i class='fa fa-refresh'></i> <?=translate('refresh')?></a>");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>home/get_messages/" + thread_id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      clearInterval(message_interval); //this clears the global message_interval
      message_interval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#msg_body").load('<?=base_url()?>home/get_messages/' + thread_id);
      }, 3000);
      $("#msg_body").removeAttr("style");
      $("#message_text").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#message_text").val('');
      $("#msg_body").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Now the `clearInterval(message_interval);` will actually clear the previous `message_interval`.